# Change dynamically created button's style if conditions met jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code, whenever I navigate to another page through my self created pagination and go back to previous page wherein I already clicked one button(clicked button will have the bootstraps' btn-success and an checked icon), the button I clicked will be on its default which is btn-primary. Now I want to keep clicked buttons style on btn-success whenever I navigate through different pages. Thank you.

```
for(var isbnCount=0; isbnCount<isbnsplitted.length; isbnCount++){
    if(value.ISBN==isbnsplitted[isbnCount]){
        console.log("true: "+isbnsplitted[isbnCount]);          
        checkBox='<td id="buttons">'+
                    '<input type="hidden" id="'+value.ISBN+value.Title+'">'+
                    '<button type="button" class="button btn btn-success" name="'+value.ISBN+'" id="'+value.ISBN+'" value="'+value.Title+'"><i class="material-icons">check</i></button>'+
                '</td>';
    }
    else{
        console.log("false");
        checkBox='<td id="buttons">'+
                        '<input type="hidden" id="'+value.ISBN+value.Title+'">'+
                        '<button type="button" class="button btn btn-primary" name="'+value.ISBN+'" id="'+value.ISBN+'" value="'+value.Title+'"><i class="material-icons">library_add</i></button>'+
                  '</td>';
    }
}   
}               
bookCards='<tr id="tableRow">'+
            '<td id="title">'+value.Title+'</td>'+
            '<td id="author">'+value.Author+'</td>'+
            '<td id="author">'+value.Category+'</td>'+
            status+
            checkBox+
      '</tr>';
$('#tableBody').append(bookCards);
```

I'm loading a new set of data's from my server side by the way, the AJAX code was above that piece of code.

Comment: I believe you are asking how to persist a user's choice? If they click a button on page 1, leave, then come back to page 1, you want the button they clicked to still be "clicked"? If so you will need to implement some sort of persistance in you database, or if you're without a database, you could use localstorage to remember which buttons were pressed.

Comment: ahmm I have done that, variable isbnsplitted comes from the ` 
`      localStorage, it looks like these,          
        var splitThis=localStorage.getItem("isbn");
 var isbnsplitted=splitThis.split(" ");   `

Comment: Did you account fro the fact that calls to local storage, although very fast, are async. Meaning there is a delay between calling the data and the data being available. Furthermore, local storage, perhaps not recommended due to is lack of cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Ahm can I ask what's the better storage I could use? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I'd like to recommend the use of Redux (just putting it out there). I've been tinkering with JQuery and Redux together on a few small apps now and they work really well together.

Redux can store all of a users settings etc, and take out much complexity of passing variables around the jQuery functions. But more than that the Redux store can be persisted and reloaded with ease, in comparison to storing variables etc. I have a JsBin working example [here](https://jsbin.com/mudasov/edit?html,css,js,output), which stores and reloads loads the Redux store.

```
// Reducer - takes the action types and reduces them into a new state condition.
const text = (state = {}, actions) =>{
  switch (actions.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_TEXT': return Object.assign({}, state, {value: actions.value})
    default: return state
  }  
}

// Store to hold state of the app - only one store but many properties. 
const updateText = Redux.createStore(text);


//Use subscribe() to update the UI in response to state changes.
updateText.subscribe(() => {
  let text = updateText.getState().value
  localStorage.setItem("text",text)
  $('#display').text(text)
});


// The only way to mutate the internal state is to dispatch an action.
// Dispatch = "Please dispatch this change, please"
$('#square').on('keyup',(e) => updateText.dispatch({type:'UPDATE_TEXT','value':e.target.value}))

$(document).ready(()=>{
  console.log('working')
  let text = localStorage.getItem("text")
  updateText.dispatch({type:'UPDATE_TEXT','value':text})
})
```

Comment: I can store the needed data for my needed condition, the problem is that I can't display the buttons' style according to its history of events. But, thank you for your suggestion I'll consider that later.

Comment: Redux can store anything in it's object store. Why not get and store the whole html for the button, including it's current class?